# Elastic Beanstalk upload and deploy doesn't work

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I want to upload a new version of my webapplication (laravel) to Elastic Beanstalk i get stuck in the uploading gui. I can click the upload button but nothing happens (also no error message, just nothing). I been using ELB for years and i never had an issue like that so it came all of a sudden and basically out of nowhere.

Comment: Can you check with EB CLI or AWS CLI?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for your answer! What do you mean by "checking"? Something like checking an error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by first only uploading the new version in the application versions overview and then manually deploying it from there. It's a good workaround but still the bug is nasty especially when there's no error message at all.